# Hybris (1808) how to customize addon through cloning

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to customize an addon (sapinvoiceaddon) and i'm trying to do it by using it as template this way:

- I add "" into
  extensioninfo.xml file of sapimvoiceaddon folder.
- Copy an extgen.properties file into same folder, and modify
  YEXTNAME_TOKEN and YCLASSPREFIX_TOKEN values with "sapinvoiceaddon"
- generate the addon using sapinvoiceaddon as template.

So, i create myaddon as a copy of sapinvoiceaddon, i add the new one in localextensions file, i execute "ant clean install" and install the addon for my storefront... all seems to be ok.
But when i try to use it in the web, i get an error as if the system was trying to locate "sapinvoiceaddon"'s files instead of "myaddon"'s ones.

What more I have to change?

The errors I get:

> WARN  [hybrisHTTP12] [ComposedTypeEJBImpl] missing jalo class
>   'de.hybris.platform.sap.sapinvoiceaddon.jalo.SapB2BDocument' for item
>   type 'SapB2BDocument' - trying supertype class instead.
>       ...
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing extension info for given extension name sapinvoiceaddon
>               at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:805)

Comment: did you generate project.properties file from the project.properties.template inside myaddon folder ?

Comment: No, Mohamed. I did not generate project.properties file, my addon folder contains a _project.properties.template_ file, but not a _project.properties_ one. May I use this one as project.properties file?

Comment: Yes ,you can copy `project.properties.template`'s properties to your new `project.properties` ( inside addon folder) or `local.propeties` file

Answer (score 1):

To create a custom addon from any exsiting addon, make sure you have following key in your addon's extensioninfo.xml

```
<meta key="extgen-template-extension" value="true"/>
```

Then you can create new addon by using this addon as template via **ant extgen** command.